# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "The operation couldn’t be

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just started ios development and I'm trying to exchange data with my api. When I'm doing POST requests everything is going fine but when I'm trying to do a GET request I get the following error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1017.)" UserInfo=0x145a2c00
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://myAPI.com/,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://myAPI.com,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x145b21d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error
>   -1017.)"}

Could someone explain what's going wrong and how I can fix it?

My request:

```
-(void)hitApiWithURL:(NSString*)url HTTPMethod:(NSString*)HTTPMethod params:(NSDictionary*)params successBlock:(successTypeBlock)success  failureBlock:(errorTypeBlock)failure{


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];


    [sessionConfig setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Content-type": @"application/json"}];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:HTTPMethod];

    // The body
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&error];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTaks = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
    [dataTaks resume];

    NSLog(@"dataTask started");

}


- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        //Gives my error
    }
    else {
        // do something:
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have something wrong with your JSON parameters:

`kCFURLErrorCannotParseResponse = -1017`

Answer (score 6):

If you forget to mention HTTPMethod, the error can also take place, I faced the Problem "NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017", somehow i forget to add line "request.HTTPMethod = "POST".

After adding the line, my code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs when you perform a `GET` request with the body set (`setHTTPBody`)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't direct solution to this case but might help someone with `-1017` error.

I had this issue after upgrading `Alamofire` from `4.8.0` to `5.2.2`. Problem was with `HTTPHeader`.

```
var authorizationHeader: HTTPHeader {
    guard let session = user?.session else {
        return HTTPHeader(name: "", value: "") 
    }
    return HTTPHeader(name: "Authorization", value: "Bearer \(session)")
}
```

Apparently sending `HTTPHeader` with empty key-value i-e `HTTPHeader(name: "", value: "")` triggers this error. I adjusted my code to instead return `nil` and it solved the issue.

Comment: In my case `session` variable was empty so header value will be `"Bearer "` (space after Bearer and nothing after it). This incomplete header also caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

For any other people who got error code `-1017` -- I fixed it by manually setting my http headers in my http request. I think the server was having problems parsing the HTTP headers because instead of the string `"Authorization" : "qii2nl32j2l3jel"` my headers didn't have the quotes like this: `Authorization : "1i2j12j"`. Good luck.

Something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* newRequestHTTPHeader = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[newRequestHTTPHeader setValue:authValue forKey:@"\"Authorization\""];
[newRequestHTTPHeader setValue:contentLengthVal forKey:@"\"Content-Length\""];
[newRequestHTTPHeader setValue:contentMD5Val forKey:@"\"Content-MD5\""];
[newRequestHTTPHeader setValue:contentTypeVal forKey:@"\"Content-Type\""];
[newRequestHTTPHeader setValue:dateVal forKey:@"\"Date\""];
[newRequestHTTPHeader setValue:hostVal forKey:@"\"Host\""];
[newRequestHTTPHeader setValue:publicValue forKey:@"\"public-read-write\""];

//the proper request is built with the new http headers.
NSMutableURLRequest* request2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:request.URL];
[request2 setAllHTTPHeaderFields:newRequestHTTPHeader];
[request2 setHTTPMethod:request.HTTPMethod];
```

Answer (score 0):

PLease check this link

```
Alamofire.request(method, "(URLString)" , parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in }
```

in post method you also add

```
parameters:parameters, encoding: .JSON
```

(if you added encoding line to GET POST then error will come "cannot parse response")

2nd please check the header as well.

```
["authentication_token" : "sdas3tgfghret6grfgher4y"]
```

then Solved this issue.

Comment: The formatting of this question needs to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

For me when send one empty header like ["":""]. Triggers this error 1017.

Solution, if you have declare:

let headers = ["":""]

the best one option is set to nil:

let headers = nil

Then you can:

sessionManager.request(
"www.example.com",
method: .post,
parameters: parameters,
encoding: encoding,
**headers: headers**
).responseJSON { response in....

Answer (score 0):

There's also a case when you use a VPN to login to your app.

When you're using a VPN, your internet traffic is routed through the VPN's servers. If you lose **internet connection** or if the VPN server **isn't reachable** (which was my use-case), the VPN might send back a response that your app isn't equipped to handle, thus resulting in the NSURLErrorCannotParseResponse (-1017) error.

In some cases, VPNs can return custom error messages or codes which your app isn't expecting and therefore can't parse correctly.

I made sure that `error.code == NSURLErrorCannotParseResponse` is in fact true which is 1017.

The only thing left is to check with your favorite reachable code if network is reachable:

```
NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "https://www.google.com")?.isReachable
```

If:

1. Network is unreachable **and**
2. Your using a VPN **and**
3. Error code is 1017

It means that there is no internet connection

We can also use [NEVPNManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/) to make sure we are in fact using our expected VPN.