# How to make HTTP request to php server in Swift iOS

Tags: php, ios, swift, nsurl

I am trying to make connection to PHP server using Swift but I am getting error and I don't know how to solve that.

Here is the code for register tapped button. I am making connection to php server and sending value via post to create a new user in the database.

```
@IBAction func registerTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let userId = userid.text;
        let user_password = password.text;
        let user_password_reaeat = repeatpassword.text;

        if(userId.isEmpty || user_password.isEmpty || user_password_reaeat.isEmpty)
        {
            displayMyAlertMessage("All Fields are required !!");
        }

        if(user_password != user_password_reaeat)
        {
            displayMyAlertMessage("Password didn't match !!");
        }


        let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://tech3i.com/varun/ios-api/userRegister.php");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL!);
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let postString = "userid=\(userId)&password=\(user_password)";

        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        {
            data, response, error in
            if(error != nil)
            {
                println("error=\(error)")
                return
            }


            var err:NSError?
            var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json
            {
                var resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String!;
                println("result:\(resultValue)")

                var isUserRegistered:Bool = false
                if(resultValue=="Success")
                {
                    isUserRegistered = true;
                }
                var messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as String!;
                if(!isUserRegistered)
                {
                    messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as String!;
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                {
                    //Display Alert messsage with confirmation
                    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message:messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
                    {
                        action in
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);
                    }
                    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion:nil);
                });
            }
        }
    task.resume()

    }



    func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
    {
        var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil);
        myAlert.addAction(okAction);
        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion:nil);
    }
```

and when I tap on the register button I  get the following error

```
error=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1017.)" UserInfo=0x79b536b0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://tech3i.com/varun/ios-api/userRegister.php, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://tech3i.com/varun/ios-api/userRegister.php, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x799cd130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1017.)"}
```

My PHP Script for create new user

```
<?php
require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");
$email = htmlentities($_POST["userid"]);
$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);

$returnValue = array();

if(empty($email) || empty($password))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "Missing required field";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($email);

if(!empty($userDetails))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "User already exists";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$secure_password = md5($password); // I do this, so that user password cannot be read even by me

$result = $dao->registerUser($email,$secure_password);

if($result)
{
$returnValue["status"] = "Success";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is registered";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

I am following video from youtube here is the link 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdW9lrB9HDw1Okk_wpFvB6DdY5f5lTfi1
its the 6th video in the playlist 
User login and Register/Sign up example using Swift on iOS. Video #3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "The operation couldn’t be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458839/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1017-the-operation-couldn-t-be)

Comment: I already tried that its not the same.

Comment: why not you using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON instead NSURL?

Comment: I didn't know about that , thats why I am not using that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add **request.HTTPMethod = "POST"** since you are trying to do a post request, aren't you?

and btw: when i try to use your URL outside of xcode, the request works (status 200). the problem seems to be in your php script:

*Notice: Undefined index: userid in /home/techicom/public_html/varun/ios-api/userRegister.php on line 4*

*Notice: Undefined index: password in /home/techicom/public_html/varun/ios-api/userRegister.php on line 5
{"status":"error","message":"Missing required field"}*

Comment: Thanks for replay but after adding this line I didn't get any message (no error and also there is no success message)

Comment: I added `&user=root&password=root` to the URL and it got to some PHP page

Comment: its because value should be sent by post method btw I included php script

Comment: ok. the problem is that you set your content-type to be *application/json* but your httpbody is not json formatted! when i change content-type to be *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* it kinda works. i get some other errors regarding your php script though...

Comment: it's too long to post it here :) *Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'techicom_varun'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/techicom/public_html/varun/ios-api/MySQLDao.php on line 21*...

Comment: I am facing the same problem if I add request.HTTPMethod=" POST" I didn't any response and if I do not include this the the same error even if I changed the content-type as you said

Comment: well... hard to tell since i do not know your complete php script. but the script is definitely the problem...

Comment: works for me now: *{"status":"Success","message":"User is registered"}* :)

Comment: ME TOO THANKS, One more question if I want to send data using get the I have to just make it request.HTTPMethod = "POST" right ???

Comment: if you want to make a GET request you do not have to set **HTTPMethod** at all since it is a GET request by default. only if you want to send a POST request you have to set **HTTPMethod = "POST"**!